# Why do we (Sefaraddim) say 'Tehilat Hashem yedabber pi...' in between 'Asher yatsar' and 'Elohai, neshama' in the morning?

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shacharis-morning-prayer

Why do we (Sefaraddim) say 'Tehilat Hashem yedabber pi...' in between 'Asher yatsar' and 'Elohai, neshama' in the morning, since we try to connect to berakhot together?

Comment: I've never heard of this. All Edot Hamizrach siddurim I've seen have had nothing between Asher Yatzar and Elokai Neshamah, with specific instructions to not pause between them.

Comment: I have two siddurim that have this. One is the Spanish and Portuguese nusah, and the other is Judeo-Spanish (Turkish & Rodesli) nusah.

Comment: If anything, it's inconsistent with general Sepharadic practice to not recite Pesukim, even in prayer, before reciting Birkot HaTorah.  (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 46:9)